# Multiple search on Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a 2 search boxes.

Car name and Car ID.
I then have a table with multiple cars in it.

Right now the live search works in livewire if i only search one field at a time.

Example:

```
        return view('livewire.table-data', [
        'data' => RDR::where('car_id', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->get()
    ]);
```

if i try add the other one in the search then it does not work at all.

```
        return view('livewire.table-data', [
        'data' => RDR::where('car_id', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('car_name', 'like', '%'.$this->carname.'%')
        ->get()
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use `when()` to conditionally apply the WHERE clause, only when a value exists in that property.

Then it depends if you want to use `where()` or `orWhere()`, the difference being *match **all** criteria* (using `where()`) or *match **any** criteria* (using `orWhere()`).

```php
return view('livewire.table-data', [
    'data' => RDR::query()
        ->when($this->car_id, function($query) {
            $query->where('car_id', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%');
        })
        ->when($this->car_name, function($query) {
            $query->where('car_name', 'like', '%'.$this->car_name.'%');
        })
        ->get(),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `where` instead of `orWhere` to return results that match both the car ID and the car name:

```js
return view('livewire.table-data', [
    'data' => RDR::where('car_id', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                 ->where('car_name', 'like', '%'.$this->carname.'%')
                 ->get()
]);
```